# Debug android data binding?

Tags: android, android-databinding

Can anyone please tell me how can I debug or find the generated code from data binding. From [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBbeQMOcnZ0) link I found out it generates the required code.

Comment: Hope this will help: http://www.androidauthority.com/android-m-data-binding-615674/

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for the auto-generated binding java files.

I was searching them too. And finally I found them in this path:

/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/*{your package}*/databinding/ActivityMainBinding.java

i.e.
/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/**com/example/databindingdtest**/databinding/ActivityMainBinding.java

Please note that this auto-generated java file is named after your layout's name according to [Google's guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html):

> ### Custom Binding Class Names
>
> By default, a Binding class is generated based on the name of the layout  file, starting it with upper-case, removing underscores ( _ ) and
> capitalizing the following letter and then suffixing “Binding”. This class
> will be placed in a databinding package under the module package. For example, the layout file contact_item.xml will generate ContactItemBinding. If the module package is com.example.my.app, then it will be placed in com.example.my.app.databinding.

Hope this can help you :-)

Answer (score -3):

You can't debug it because it generates necessary code only at the compile time.

Comment: So you are saying there is no way to debug bound layouts?

Comment: bongo, yep, sorry my mistake. Sushant, yes, as far as i know you can't debug it

Comment: That's right, someone asked this question to the data binding devs at Android Dev Summit : https://youtu.be/NBbeQMOcnZ0?t=29m47s

Comment: How does the fact the code is generated (either at compile time or at runtime) affect its ability to be run with debugger? Doesn't make sense to me