# Android Studio is creating debug packages

Tags: android-studio

I have created an Android project. Somehow `Android Studio` is create weird packages, I wonder why?

I tried to delete them as well, but they recreated themselves.

Android Studio Version:

```
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Canary 11
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debug android data binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176948/debug-android-data-binding)

Comment: Unfortunately not